# any tools for working with pg_dump .backup files?

Tags: postgresql

I have a bunch of binary .backup generated by the PostgreSQL pg_dump program.
I am trying to rebuild the most complete/inclusive version of the DB from this collection of files. Because it's a binary format, diff and comm comparisons are not working.
PsotgreSQL allows me to load (pg_restore) one of these files at a time but that's about it.
How can I go about comparing the contents of these different backups to rebuild a maximal DB?

Note: all are dumped from Postgres 9.0.x

Comment: `pg_restore` can generate scripts (if you ommit a destination db) which could be analyzed with diff. (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-pgrestore.html)

Answer (score 0):

The tool is `pg_restore.`  You can use it to extract data or structure from arbitrary entities in your binary dumps.

For example to extract just the table data from a table called "foo" we could:

```
pg_restore -a -t foo mybackup.backup
```